AWS Glue Job stucks in running state when I do post request in the script
I'm new to AWS Glue Jobs,
I have a slack URL in which I want to do a post request to post a message in my bot channel.
But when I do a post request on that slack URL, my job keeps itself in Running state until I stop running it or it has reached the timeout.
import requests

data = {
  "channel": "my_channel",
  "text": "hello"
}
r = requests.post(slack_url, data=json.dumps(data))

When I run the above code with my other code, The program keeps itself running.
What changes should I make so that my application can do a post request to any external API?

Was the message successfully posted to the slack channel?

No. It doesn't. when I add r = requests.post(slack_url, data=json.dumps(data)) program doesn't prints anything, even the print statements that I add at the start of the script.
